# How to handle clicks on the rows of listView, while notifyDataSetChanged might be called?

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, android-selector

### Background

I have a complex adapter for a listView.

Each row has some inner views that need to be clickable (and hande the clicks), and they also have selectors (to show the effect of touching).

on some cases, notifyDataSetChanged() needs to be called quite frequently (for example once/twice a second), to show some changes on the listView's items.

As an example, consider seeing a list of downloading files, where you show the user the progress of each file being downloaded.

### The problem

Each time notifyDataSetChanged is called, the touch event is lost on the touched view, so the user can miss clicking on it , and especially miss long clicking on it.

Not only that, but the selector also loses its state, so if you touch it and see the effect, when the notifyDataSetChanged is called, the view loses its state and you see it as if it isn't get touched.

This happens even for views that have nothing in them being updated (meaning I just return the convertView for them) .

### Sample code

The code below demonstrates the problem. It is not the original code but a super short sample to make it clear what I'm talking about.

Again, this is not the original code, so I've removed the ViewHolder usage and taking care of the clicking to do some operations, in order to make it simple to read and understand. But it's still the same logic.

Here's the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final BaseAdapter adapter = new BaseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;
                if (tv == null) {
                    tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.item_background_selector));
                    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(final View v) {
                            android.util.Log.d("AppLog", "click");
                        }
                    });
                }
                //NOTE: putting the setOnClickListener here won't help either.
                final int itemViewType = getItemViewType(position);
                tv.setText((itemViewType == 0 ? "A " : "B ") + System.currentTimeMillis());
                return tv;
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
                return position % 2;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(final int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(final int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 100;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(final int position) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // fake notifying
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                android.util.Log.d("AppLog", "notifyDataSetChanged");
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

**item_background_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

### Partial solution

It's possible to update only the needed views, by finding the view and then calling getView on it, but this is a workaround.
Also, it won't work in the case of adding/removing items from the listView, which needs to have notifyDataSetChangedbeing called. Plus it also makes the updated view to lose its touching state.

EDIT: even the partial solution doesn't work. Maybe it's causing a layout of the entire listView, which causes the other views to lose their states.

### The question

How can I let views stay "in sync" with the touch events after calling notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: What happens exactly on touch? If you maintain the state and call notifydatasetchanged() at end of click listener, it should work

Comment: on some cases, notifyDataSetChanged() needs to be called quite frequently (for example once/twice a second), to show some changes on the listView's items. - You should rethink on it. Why is this a requirement?

Comment: Have you tried using the `onTouchEvent` ? Maybe it fires the command by executing in the `ACTION_UP` event

Comment: @MadhurAhuja I need to update what is shown on the screen. Sometimes you don't have a totally static listView. For example, when you show a list of downloading files, you'd want to show their progress. Have you tried out the sample I've written? What do you mean by "maintain the state" ?

Comment: @mapo good idea, but I've now tried it, and it catches only the first event (touch down). nothing more... if I return "true" , I get most of the events (and even ACTION_CANCEL) , but I also lose the selector.

Comment: so it is not solving your problem when you just catch the state for `ACTION_DOWN`. The long click event would be lost, but you have at least the click event.

Comment: @mapo almost, since the user might click a tiny moment before notifyDataSetChanged is called, which will lose the clicking effect. Also, clicking isn't handled on ACTION_DOWN. It's handled on ACTION_UP, to differentiate between long clicking, scrolling, clicking, etc... For now, it's the best solution I can find, but it's not a good one too... :(

Comment: @mapo Actually, now that I try it, it seems that it should work (when returning "true" for the touch listener) . The actions I get match exactly what I should handle. Question is, how do I let the selector of the view handle the current state too? I mean, how do I let the effect of touching to be visible to the user?

Comment: @mapo I could change the state of the background drawable of the view, but is this a legitimate operation? Could it cause any problem with the view and how it is being shown ?

Comment: i think you could make your own custom animation of the view. so as you touch it you can change the background color of the view with a transition, so yes, i think its a legitamte operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you can use the `View.setOnTouchListener()` and catch the `ACTION_DOWN` and the `ACTION_UP` Event.

For the Selector Animation you can use your Custom Color Animation. Here is an example for changing the backgroundColor with an Animation.

```
 Integer colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
 Integer colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
 ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
 colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

     @Override
     public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
         view.setBackgroundColor((Integer)animator.getAnimatedValue());
     }

 });
 colorAnimation.start();
```

---

### Alternative solution

EDIT (by the OP, meaning the thread-creator): An alternative solution, based on the above, is to use the touchListener to set the state of the background of the view.

The disadvantage of it (though it should be fine for most cases) is that if the list gets more/less items, the touch is lost (by ACTION_CANCEL) , so, if you wish to handle it too, you could use this event and handle it yourself using your own logic.

Even though the solution is a bit weird and doesn't handle all possible states, it works fine.

Here's a sample code:

```
public static abstract class StateTouchListener implements OnTouchListener,OnClickListener
    {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v,final MotionEvent event)
      {
      final Drawable background=v.getBackground();
      // TODO use GestureDetectorCompat if needed
      switch(event.getAction())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
          background.setState(new int[] {});
          v.invalidate();
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          background.setState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed});
          v.invalidate();
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          background.setState(new int[] {});
          v.invalidate();
          v.performClick();
          onClick(v);
          break;
        }
      return true;
      }
    }
```

and the fix in my code:

```
tv.setOnTouchListener(new StateTouchListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v)
      {
      android.util.Log.d("Applog","click!");
      };
  });
```

This should replace the setOnClickListener I used.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand why I need to add animation, and where this code should be added to .

Comment: Sorry, i thought you wanted the standard click Animation. Otherwise you just can use `setBackgroundColor` for changing the background color for your view when clicking on the view and change it back after a time

Comment: I didn't know there is a standard click animation . but if it exists, why do I need to add a custom one instead of what's available already? Anyway, how do I set the state of the view? I know it's probably possible to use "v.getBackground().setState(...)" , but sometimes the views inside or outside need to change their state accordingly (using "duplicateParentState" for example) ...

Comment: I've noticed this only works if I update the view without notifyDataSetChanged, but as I wrote, this is a bit problematic as items can be removed and inserted. But maybe it's ok, since the order can be changed, and the item can be moved to other places (or be removed).

Comment: May I edit your answer to include the solution you've suggested, which also includes what I've written that's missing from your idea?

Comment: ok i've edited it. now it should be fine. if you have any suggestions to improve it, please write about it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating click listener of "Recycled" views.

Place `tv.setOnClickListener()` out of the `if (tv == null)` check.

Also, the properties you want to "stay synced" should be in the model backing the ListView. Never trust Views to hold important data, they should only reflect data from model.

```
class Item{
  String name;
  boolean enabled;  
  boolean checked
}


class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{


 @Override
        public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null){
       // create new instance
    }

    // remove all event listeners

    Item item = getItem(position);

    // set view properties from item (some times, old event listeners will fire when changing view properties , so we have cleared event listeners above)

    // setup new event listeners to update properties of view and item
 }

}
```

Comment: No, this won't help (and I've checked it already). the same view doesn't need to get a new onClickListener again and again. In fact, what I've written is an optimized way of avoiding more and more GCs .

Comment: About the "stay synced", what is the solution? I want to have both clicking on the listView inner views, and also be able to update the listView items.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Only if all views did the same action (as in your example), In actual cases, views will need to raise click events for that particular item index/id, then this approach would not work.

Comment: I don't understand. As I've already written, the code above is not the real code I use. It's more complex, and it will handle the clicked view correctly (when it gets the event). Please watch "the world of listView" lecture by Google . They explain there about ViewHolder usage, which can help you a lot with handling views in listView . Maybe I should write more notes in the question to make it clear.

Comment: @androiddeveloper updated answer. You can maintain all important properties in Item class, so that they are persisted, even if views are recycled.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. I've tested this already. Also it's not optimized to use ViewHolder and the item the view is currently showing. I suggest you watch "the world of listView" lecture. Removing the touch events also doesn't make sense, since you already set it again right after it. Of course, what you've written works in the general way, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Views are Recycled, a recycled view which was previously at number 10 is now appearing at number 15, If you don't re-set event listeners , it will fire Old event listeners , which will still see position as 10 as it was when the old event handlers were created as anonymous inner classes. This has nothing to do with View Holder pattern. You can use the same pattern here as well. Concrete answer can only be given for original code. Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Your code doesn't answer the question. I used both methods. Also, I already know about recycled views, but if you call notifyDataSetChanged, the exact same views are used, and I already do checks to verify the data, but again, this is not the issue ,and not the question I ask here. I've now updated the code to show that using your code won't help (putting onClickListener after the "if" block ) .

Comment: Please try out your code before you claim this is the cause to the problem. I already know how to handle listViews and adapters. This is only a sample to show the problem. Of course I won't present you hundreds of irrelevant lines of code...